# Euler Totient function equal 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I am asked to find when $\phi (n) =1$. It seems it should be trivial, but I am not sure if my proof is correct or convincing, as it may be lacking in formality.

A look at http://primefan.tripod.com/Phi500.html shows that it is only true when $n=1,2$. Leaving those two cases aside, I would prove that $\phi(n)\neq 1$ if $n\geq 3$. To move on I would consider the two cases when $n$ is even or odd. If $n$ is odd then it is at least $\phi(n)\geq 2$ because $\gcd(2,n)=1$. But if $n$ is even? For any $n\geq 3$ there should be at least a prime $p$ among the set of numbers that define the totient function, then $\phi(n)\geq 2.$

Comment: note that $\phi(n) = \prod_{p^k \| n} \phi(p^k) = \prod_{p^k \| n} (p^k-p^{k-1})$ where $p^k \| n$ means $p$ is prime and $p^{k}$ divides $n$ but $p^{k+1}$ doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n\geq 3$, then $1$ and $n-1$ are two different numbers coprime to $n$. Thus, $\phi(n) \geq 2$.